# can anyone sort this error out in Glide context

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm having error in Glide,

this error is this

can anyone sort this error out pls i need help
its build perfectly fine but im facing the error at runtime

this line is causing main problem

`Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.disc).into(holder.sound_dis);`

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.paradox.projectsp3, PID: 27908
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:29)
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:23)
        at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:768)
        at com.paradox.projectsp3.Adapter.DemoAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DemoAdapter.java:44)
        at com.paradox.projectsp3.Adapter.DemoAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DemoAdapter.java:19)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23304)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6539)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23304)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6539)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23304)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6539)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:536)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23304)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6539)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23304)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6539)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1841)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23304)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6539)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:871)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23304)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6539)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3979)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3380)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2345)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9046)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1066)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:889)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:816)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1051)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8282)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
```

this is my adapter im using

```
package com.paradox.projectsp3.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.paradox.projectsp3.Model.MediaObject;
import com.paradox.projectsp3.R;

import java.util.List;

public class DemoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DemoAdapter.DemoViewHolder> {



    List<MediaObject> mediaObjectList;
    private ImageView imageView;
    public Context context;


    public DemoAdapter(List<MediaObject> mediaObjectList,Context context) {
        this.mediaObjectList = mediaObjectList;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DemoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup , int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_main,viewGroup,false);
        return new DemoViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( DemoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MediaObject mediaObject = mediaObjectList.get(position);
        Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.disc).into(holder.sound_dis);

        }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mediaObjectList.size();
    }

    public class DemoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView sound_dis;


        public DemoViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            ImageView sound_dis = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **sound_dis** is null because you accidentally created a local variable in your DemoViewHolder constructor and stored the ImageView reference in it. The one declared in the class has no value (null).

In your DemoViewholder function remove ImageView data type as you have already declared it in your DemoviewHolder class .

Your DemoViewHolder constructor should be like this :

```
public DemoViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        sound_dis = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error in glide , actually you have declared imageview wrongly. Your DemoViewHolder will be like this , then it will work fine.

```
public class DemoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView sound_dis;


    public DemoViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        sound_dis = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);


    }
}
```

Comment: @paradoxcodee have you added your image view like this ?

Comment: yes i did it worked